# Android Pull To Refresh onFresh method not being called

Tags: java, android, pull-to-refresh

I am using Johan Nilsson Android Pull to Refresh library in my android application. The problem I am having is that the onRefresh method seems to not being called (since none of my logs are displayed) what is causing this and how do I fix it.

```
 public class MyFragment  extends RoboFragment implements ResponseListener<List<TimelineItem>>{

    @InjectView (R.id.TwitterList)  private PullToRefreshListView listView;
private List<TimelineItem> results;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container,false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.v("onRefresh", "done");
            new FetchNewData().execute("");

        }
    });

    TimelineTask request = new TimelineTask(getActivity());
    request.onResponseListener(this);

    request.execute(new String());
}


/**
 * Callback handler that is called
 * after data is fetched from server.
 * @author mario
 */
public void onComplete(List<TimelineItem> result)
{
    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty())
    {
        this.results = result;
        Collections.sort(results,Collections.reverseOrder());
        TimelineAdapter adapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.fragment_timeline_item, results);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);   

    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Account! Available Please an Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}//end onComplete method




private class FetchNewData extends AsyncTask<String, Void,List<TimelineItem> >
{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<TimelineItem> result) 
    {
        results.addAll(result);
        listView.onRefreshComplete();
        Log.v("onPostExecuted", "done");
    }

    @Override
    protected List<TimelineItem> doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        Log.v("doInBackground", "done");
        Collections.sort(results);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you setting the refresh listener in `onViewCreated` and not `onCreate`?

Comment: Because I want the listener to be attached after the view is created but I don't think that's why I'm having this problem

Comment: That's fine, but I think you've over-complicating your implementation. Not sure why you're overriding `onCreateView()` and `onViewCreated()`. I've used this library and attached the listener in `onCreate()` and never had any issues.

Comment: I'm using this within a fragement